# nginx config regexp block excluding homepage

Tags: configuration, nginx

I would like to block all the http_user_agents which identify as bots, but let them to the homepage.
for example i have url:
https://test.mydomain.org/xyz....
need to request for crawlers only to homepage https://test.mydomain.org/ but not to https://test.mydomain.org/xyz...
what regexp should be valid for my situation ?

Have tried this for my nginx conf:

```
.
.
.
location ~* (/.*)$ {
    if ($limit_bots = 1) {
    return 403;
}
.
.
.
```

Comment: `robots.txt` is not enough for your use case?

Comment: thanks, but no, required from server side.